# Encoutering OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket when setting up a basic http proxy with python

Tags: python, sockets, http, server, proxy

I was trying to set up a simple http-proxy using python but I keep getting OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket on `data = conn.recv(1024)`

What am I doing wrong? My main function

```
def main():
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        s.bind((HOST, PORT))
        s.listen()

        while True:
            conn, addr = s.accept()
            # get the next valid HTTP request
            buffer = b''
            while True:

                with conn:
                    print('Connected by: ', addr)
                data = conn.recv(1024)
                if not data:
                    break
                buffer = buffer + data;

                req, buffer = parse_message(buffer)
                if req is not None:
                    print('success');
```

Comment: The `with conn:` block is more than likely closing the socket `conn` when it exits. Remove this block

Comment: lit answer! @IainShelvington I have been thinking it is the ```with``` statement but forgort about the ```conn```

Comment: i got this error when running flask from cmd within PyCharm. Switched to Windows CMD Window and the error is gone.